# Positive part of functions from Sobolev space involving time

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Assume that $u \in W^{1,2}(0,T; W_0^{1,2}(\Omega))$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T <+\infty$.

Let $A \subset \Omega \times (0, T)$ be a Lipschitz domain such that $u(\cdot,t_0) \leq 0$ on $\partial (A \cap \{t=t_0\})$ for a.a. $t_0 \in (0, T)$ in the sense of traces of functions from $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$.

> Is it true that $\max(u, 0)|_{A} \in W^{1,2}(0,T;W_0^{1,2}(\Omega))$?

(Here under $\max(u, 0)|_{A}$ I mean a function $w$ such that $w = \max(u,0)$ on $A$ and $w=0$ on $(\Omega \times (0, T)) \setminus A$).

P.S. Analogous property is, of course, valid for functions from $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$.

[Added] The question is also actual for the space $W^{1,2}(0,T;L^2(\Omega)) \cap L^2(0,T;W_0^{1,2}(\Omega))$.

Comment: If $A\subset \Omega\times (0,T)$ then $A\times \{t=t_0\}\subset \Omega\times (0,T)\times (0,T)$, which is not what you want. Is it $A\subset\Omega$ or $A\cap \{t=t_0\}$?

Comment: @Gio67 The second case is what I wanted. Thanks for pointing out this typo!

Comment: I doubt that $\max(u,0) \in W^{1,2}(0,T; W^{1,2}(\Omega))$. It should be possible to prove that $\max(u,0) \in W^{1,2}(L^2)\cap L^2(W^{1,2})$.